# What is the difference between require('path'); and require('path').resolve; in terms of performance in this examples?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I do not have much knowledge so I try to understand as best I can, the way the code execution happens using Node JS.

```
//Sample script A 

const path = require('path');

function A (){
return path.resolve(__dirname, 'some relative path');
}
```

In terms of performance exist some difference, between these two examples?

```
//Sample script B

const resolve = require('path').resolve;

function B (){
return resolve(__dirname, 'some relative path');
}
```

If you boys and girls can give an elaborate answer it's better,
I don't speak English natively, sorry for any mistakes.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Both are pretty much identical, they maybe a slight performance gain with the second version as it has property access it doesn't need to resolve each time.

Comment: -Keith Can explain more to me?

Answer (score -1):

The `path` module provides utilities or API for working with file and directory paths. you can include it in your project using

`const path = require('path');  //module`

The `path.resolve()` method resolves a sequence of paths or path segments into an absolute path.

`const resolve = require('path').resolve`

here we are just getting the resolve method from path module

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very clear about module and method, but the question is about differences in terms of performance, between both examples, I know bot are over simplified.